# How to populate an array inside a document which stores uniqueID as strings and that uniqueID is from another collection rather than objectID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user document as follows which holds an array of systemIDs', which is unique for another collection which holds systemID as unikey key. How to populate user with  all system ID details?

User document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("6gfg85993266db5fdgs578"), 
    "email" : "xyz@gmail.com", 
    "role" : "user", 
    "systemIDs" : [
        "12345678", 
        "87654321"
    ], 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-02-13T16:31:34.119+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-02-13T16:31:34.119+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
},

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("6gfg85993266db5fdgs578"), 
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com", 
    "role" : "user", 
    "systemIDs" : [
        "1111111",
        "2135684"
    ], 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-02-13T16:31:34.119+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-02-13T16:31:34.119+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

System IDs document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62093fdsfsdfs97e1"), 
    "systemID" : "12345678", 
    "err" : [
        1, 5, 10
    ], 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
},

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62093fdsfsdfs97e1"), 
    "systemID" : "87654321", 
    "err" : [
        3, 7
    ], 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
},

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62087dsfsdfs97e1"), 
    "systemID" : "11111111", 
    "err" : [
        
    ], 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
},
```

I want to find details of all the systemIDs a user holds which results something like this if I query my users collection with email : xyz@gmail.com, I should get the below result or populated result like shown:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("6gfg85993266db5fdgs578"), 
    "email" : "xyz@gmail.com", 
    "role" : "user", 
    "systemIDs" : [
        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("62093fdsfsdfs97e1"), 
            "systemID" : "12345678", 
            "err" : [
                1, 5, 10
            ], 
            "__v" : NumberInt(0)
        },

        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("62093fdsfsdfs97e1"), 
            "systemID" : "87654321", 
            "err" : [
                3, 7
            ], 
            "__v" : NumberInt(0)
        },

    ]
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-02-13T16:31:34.119+0000"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-02-13T16:31:34.119+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
},
```

I can create a foreach loop and call database each time but I suppose that wouldn't be a good practice.
I am new with this so please bear with me and explain it to me in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use aggregation with `$match` and `$lookup` to perform this task

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "systems",
      "localField": "systemIDs",
      "foreignField": "systemID",
      "as": "systemIDs"
    }
  }
])
```

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/61CAneakcRU)